# What will happen If I initialize a Class object which is already initialized in JAVA?

Tags: java, memory-management, java-memory-leaks

I want to know what will happen if I initialize an already initialized Class object in Java. Does the garbage collector destroys the object and free the memory?.

**Example code:**

```
........
Object target = new MyClass();//First intialization
........
target = new MyClass();//Re-intialization //I want to know what will happen here
........
```

Comment: This does not constitute 'initializ[ing] a Class object'. Nor does anything here constitute 're-iniitalizing' anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object target = new MyClass();
```

This will create a new object of MyClass() and `target` variable will refer to this object.

After the second statement:

```
target = new MyClass();
```

Another new Object will be created and `target` will now refer to this newly created object. The previous object will have no reference and **GC** will free that memory.

Comment: @BharathAsl Happy to help. Welcome :)

Comment: Ruhul, It answers my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The first object of MyClass will no longer be active on the thread, the garbage collector will activate and free the space when it needs more memory on the heap, which is a large chunk of memory used by the Java Virtual Machine.